# Why doesn't roundf() round a float value and why do int - float math operations return wrong values?

Tags: c, floating-point

I don't understand why doesn't the `roundf()` function from `math.h` round the `donation` variable, whilst it rounds `livestockPM` without a problem. I need to use the rounded values for other calculations, but I'm using `printf` to check if the values are correct, and it simply returns wrong values (doesn't round variable `donation`). Also, the variable `final` only returns values as if rounded to .00, doesn't matter what variables `farmer1`,2,3 hold.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
   int farmer1 = 9940;
   int farmer2 = 4241;
   int farmer3 = 7779;

   float livestockPM = (float)farmer1 / (float)farmer2;
   printf("livestock: %f\n",livestockPM);

   livestockPM = roundf(livestockPM * 100) / 100;
   printf("livestock rounded: %f\n",livestockPM);

   float donation = (float)livestockPM * (float)farmer3;
   printf("donation: %f\n", donation);

   donation = roundf(donation * 100.00) / 100.00;
   printf("donation rounded: %f\n", donation);

   float final = donation * (float)farmer2;
   printf("final: %f\n", final);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
livestock: 2.343787
livestock rounded: 2.340000
donation: 18202.859375
donation rounded: 18202.859375
final: 77198328.000000
```

Anyone got any idea why? I was thinking because of multiplying float with int, but I can't seem to get it work like this. I've tried removing the (float) from integer variables, but the results were undesirable as well. Thanks.

Comment: `float` only has 6 or 7 digits of precision. Change all your `float`s to `double`, and use `round`, not `roundf`.

Comment: @user3386109 thank you, actually worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP's `float` is encoded using *binary* floating point and `18202.859375` lacks precision to take on a value that `"%f"` prints as `18202.860000`.

A `float` cannot represent every possible number.  As a binary floating point number it can represent numbers like below.  See [IEEE 754 Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), but not in between.

```
18202.859375
18202.86138125
```

When the following executes, the best possible result is again `18202.859375`.

```
float donation_rounded = roundf(18202.859375 * 100.00) / 100.00;
```

Recall that `printf("%f\n", x)` prints a number rounded textually to the closest 0.000001 value.

Code could use `double`, but the same problem will occur with very large numbers, but may meet OP''s immediate need. [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943115/why-doesnt-roundf-round-a-float-value-and-why-do-int-float-math-operations/40943418#comment69097581_40943115)

---

As OP appears to be trying to cope with money, there is no *great* solution in standard C. [best money/currency representation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214586/2410359) goes into some of the issues.