# How do I isolate the cents from a dollar.cent amount?

Tags: c

New to programming. Taking class in C. Below is my attempt at a program that will print "What is your hourly wage?" then read the dollar.cent amount and calculate salary. Then print the salary in the form, "Your total income over a year is X dollars and Y cents.

To isolate dollars from the dollar.cent amount, I truncated the value by converting to an int from a double. I wasn't sure how to get the cents, so I figured I could subtract the dollars from the dollars.cents (*100) and I'd have the number of cents.

I run the program and it works fine, except I don't get the amount of cents I expect.

If the user enters 18.33 as the hourly wage. Then I get 31826 for total Dollars, 31836.40 for total Income. But when I subtract them and multiply by 100, I am given 39 cents instead of 40.

```
int main(void) {

double totalIncome       = 0.0;
int totalDollars         = 0;
int totalCents           = 0;
double hourlyWage        = 0.0;
int hoursPerWeek         = 40;
const int WEEKS_PER_YEAR = 52;

printf("What is your hourly wage? ");
scanf("%lf", &hourlyWage);

totalIncome = hourlyWage * hoursPerWeek * WEEKS_PER_YEAR;
totalDollars = totalIncome; //converts to int from double
totalCents = 10 * (totalIncome - totalDollars);

printf("Your total income over a year is %d dollars and %d cents", totalDollars, totalCents);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you compile with `-Wall`, do you get any warnings? I think that how you're assigning totalCents might lead to a loss of precision. But I'm not 100% sure. Compile with that flag, and check.

Comment: I came up with this hack solution... totalCents = ((totalIncome + 0.005) - totalDollars) * 100 ;

Comment: I don't know what you mean by -Wall  I'm verrrry new to this

Comment: try totalCents = fmod(totalIncome, 10)

Comment: If you use GCC as your compiler, using `gcc -Wall …` will add a lot more helpful diagnostics, basically pointing out errors in your program that you should fix before running it.  If you use `gcc -Wall -Werror …`, you'll have to fix them as they'll be errors, not warnings.  If you're using MS Visual Studio, you should check whether you get better warnings if you use `cl /W3` — if not, check the manual.

Comment: @AlexButterfield `int totalCents = ((totalIncome + 0.005) - totalDollars) * 100` fails for many negative numbers and large numbers, fails for many edge conditions.  Consider `totalIncome = 123.9999`.  You idea will end up with 123 dollars and 100 cents.  C has a good library in `<math.h>` with many _round_ functions -use those

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `100*(totalIncome - totalDollars)` is not exactly 40, but `3.999999999941792e+01`, thus casting it to `int` yields 39. This is a good example why one should never use floating points for computations with currencies.

BTW: You can simply avoid this issue altogether using something like
`scanf("%d.%d", &hourlyDollars, &hourlyCents);`

Comment: Love this solution, but if the user puts 10 as opposed to 10.00 what will happen there? Will this still work?

Comment: Yes, it will actually just read 10 into `hourlyDollars`. However, this might not be the most reliable solution to cover all cases, but your initial solution did not perform any checks either.

Answer (score 1):

To take a floating point money to floating point cents to the nearest whole number, use `round()` or `rint()`

```
double x;
double cents = rint(x * 100.0);
```

To take a floating point money to nearest integer cents, use `lround()` or `llround()`

```
long long cents = llround(x * 100.0);
```

To break into FP dollars into whole dollars and whole cents, scale, round and then separate.

```
double x;
double cents = rint(x * 100.0);
double cent =  fmod(cents, 100.0);
double dollar = (cents - cent)/100;
```

---

Avoid mixing types to support money.  Use `long long` or `double`.  Each has its [short comings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214586/2410359).  For learner programs start with wide integer types of the smallest denomination (cents).