# How does (floor) work in C? Strange result with var=4.2 when multiplying 100 and calling (floor)

Tags: c, integer, cs50, floor

How does (floor) actually work in C?
According to techonthenet . com ,

> In the C Programming Language, the floor function returns the largest
>   integer that is smaller than or equal to x (ie: rounds downs the
>   nearest integer).

After entering value 4.2 into get_float(), 
I use floor(4.2 * 100), to turn them into cents and remove decimal places and make it into an integer.

However, I am perplexed why entering the value specifically 4.2 will return a different value for both floor(4.2 * 100), and floor(4.2 * 1000 / 10)?
Does this have something to do with imprecision?

See image:
[When variable entered as 4.2, floor produces different values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8orG.png)

Btw, I am totally new to this just started CS50 on edx, and trying out the last exercise of week 1's lesson.. would also love any comments on other parts of the code.
More info on the problem here:
http://docs.cs50.net/problems/greedy/greedy.html

Comment: *Does this have something to do with imprecision* - yes.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Helper exercise: write `1/3` as a decimal point number then multiply the decimal point number you wrote with `3`. Did you get exactly `1`? Don't cheat! Figure out how much is `floor(3*1/3)` using the values you just calculated. A similar thing happens in computers for all numbers that cannot be written as `m/n` with `n` being a positive integral power of `2`.

Comment: There's a [cs50 stack exchange](http://cs50.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this have something to do with imprecision?

It has everything to do with imprecision.

You cannot represent an infinite number of floating point values with a finite number of bits, so what actually gets stored in a floating point type is an *approximation* for most values.  `4.2` cannot be represented *exactly* in a 32-bit `float` type; what actually gets stored is something closer to `4.199999809`.  <strike>You need 48 bits in the significand to represent it exactly, meaning you need to use a 64-bit `double`.</strike>

*=sigh=* I can't add.  `double` gets you a helluva lot closer to 4.2, but not exactly.

And that's just talking about storage, not about rounding and error propagation in arithmetic operations.

In general, it's better to use `double` instead of `float` for floating-point work (greater range *and* precision).  Also, it's better to store currency amounts in integral types, scaled to the smallest unit (for example, instead of storing `4.2` dollars, store `420` cents, or `4200` mils).  You'll still need to use floating point types for computing interest and things like that, but you'll want to *store* those results back to an integral type after doing the proper rounding and scaling.

Comment: "You need 48 bits in the significand to represent it exactly, ... use a 64-bit double" --> 4.2 can not be represented exactly as a FP binary `double` either.   Request clarity on why 48 and its application here.

Comment: @chux - I can't add.  Struck the offending passage.

Comment: Much better without the "48".  Good and correct use of rare `mils`.  Trivia: various US money units: mil, cent, dime, dollar, eagle.

Answer (score 1):

`float/double` cannot represent every possible number exactly.  Typical [`float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) can represent about 2<sup>32</sup> different numbers.  4.2 is not one of them.  Instead, the nearest value is used.  Print [using `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359) to see enough precision of the number to know it is not exactly 4.2

```
#include <float.h> 
float a = 4.2f;
printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, a);
// 4.19999981e+08

a *= 100;
printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, a);
// 4.19999969e+02

a = floor(a);
printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, a);
// 4.19000000e+02
```

With `a*100` and `a*1000` the products incur rounding to the nearest repesentrable answer and recall, `a` is not *exactly* 4.2.

```
a = 4.2;
printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, a * 100);     // 4.19999969e+02
printf("%f\n", floor(a * 100));                   // 419.000000
printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, a * 1000);    // 4.20000000e+03
printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, a * 1000/10); // 4.20000000e+02
printf("%f\n", floor(a * 1000 / 10));             // 420.000000
```

---

Using `floor()` is a poor choice to separate 4.2 into an whole number and fraction when the number needs to be rounded to the nearest 0.01.  Instead, scale, round and then separate using matching type functions.

```
  float a100 = a*100;
  printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, a100);    // 4.19999969e+02
  a100 = roundf(a100);
  printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, a100);    // 4.20000000e+02
  float a100th = fmodf(a100, 100);
  printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, a100th);  // 2.00000000e+01
  a = (a100 - a100th)/100;
  printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, a);       // 4.00000000e+00
```

---

*Money* has many special concerns in C and various approaches have their [weaknesses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214586/2410359).  Using `float` is a very weak choice.

Answer (score 0):

Print the value of dollars to see what is actually stored before you try to floor the value.